# How to Delete one Unique Record from All tables in Mysql

Tags: java, javascript, php, mysql, sql

Here are my tables

table1:

```
id  mark      
01   80
02  100
```

table2:

```
id  subject    
01  80
02  100
```

I want to delete id 01 record in both tables at the same time in one query 
this code is not working

```
s2.executeUpdate("Delete from * where Student_ID = '"+mng_stu_stuid.getText()+"' ");
```

Comment: If it's available for you to modify the MySQL database being queried, I would look into [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. DML (Data Manipulation Language) queries affect only one table a time.

Comment: Use Single transaction not single query.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view in MySQL. Then deleting record from view will delete records from all table in the view. The only thing to watch out for, is permissions

Some views are updatable. That is, you can use them in statements such as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT to update the contents of the underlying table. For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table. There are also certain other constructs that make a view nonupdatable.

Source : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html

Comment: This is a good idea if the data in in each table will be the same (e.g. 100 records in Table A and 100 records in Table B with the same ID)

Answer (score 0):

if you use mysql look at [DELETE Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html)

you can write follow code:

```
delete table1, table2 from table1, table2 where table1.id='01' and table2.id='01'
```